# Does the size of a Venn diagram indicate the cardinality of the set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Since a Venn diagram is a schematic representation, does the size of the Venn diagram have any meaning?

Comment: It's certainly possible to make it so that the size is proportional to the cardinality, but I don't think that this is always assumed or used.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, no, because just reproducing faithfully the intersections on a $2$-d sheet of paper is enough of a technical difficulty without bothering with estimates of the areas.

---

The usual way to encode cardinality effectively in a Venn diagram is by labelling each region with its own.

Comment: Well, if $A \subset B$, then $A$ will be inside $B$ and then smaller. So the size has a meaning in some way.

Comment: @nicomezi I'd say that it's not quite the size of the set that matters, but how you intersect it.

Comment: I agree with you, no doubt on this. But size has (implicitely) a meaning in the case described in my last comment. So I would say it can have a meaning. But I would definitely not rely on this.

Comment: Ok, but the fact is that, for instance, in a generic diagram of three sets, the three subsets in the form $A\cap B\setminus C$ will often tend, for geometric reasons, to look similar in size and perhaps smaller than $A\cap B\cap C$, despite those sizes not being related at all. Of course, it is entirely possible to make a deformation that goes around this, but usually this thing is not implemented.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The whole point of Venn diagrams is simply to visualize all possibilities as far as objects belonging or not belonging to some category or set of objects.

Indeed, even when a set $A$ is a subset of a set $B$, you don't draw set $A$ completely within set $B$; that's something an [Euler Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram) would do, but not a Venn diagram. If in a Venn diagram you want to indicate that $A$ is a subset of $B$, you can 'black out' the region inside $A$ and outside $B$, but you still show that region. So, the best you can do with Venn diagrams is to show that there are or are not objects in the possible regions, but there is no indication of relative cardinality, let alone absolute soze.